# Range Partitions by Date with One Partition for NULL dates

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have a table with deleted column containing the date the item was soft-deleted.  Rows with NULL value in deleted column are the active ones.  I was not able to figure our the syntax to create a partition for null values in deleted column.  What is the syntax of creating such column?

```
create table my_table_pointing(street_id int, p_city_id int, name varchar(10), deleted date)
PARTITION BY RANGE (deleted);

CREATE TABLE my_table_pointing_2020 PARTITION OF my_table_pointing
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01') TO ('2021-01-01');


   CREATE TABLE my_table_pointing_active PARTITION OF my_table_pointing
     "for all rows where date is null"...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a filtered index with `where deleted is null` is more helpful in this case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  incrementally pre-organizing your data to make some future action more efficient is one of the important uses of partitioning.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, But that should only happen once per row, I assume.  No different from deleting from an active table and inserting into a history table.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are on PG11 or later, you can create a default partition, and rows with `deleted is null` will be routed there.

```
create table my_table_pointing_active partition of my_table_pointing default;
```

Comment: Might he also want to create a check constraint asserting `deleted IS NULL`?

Comment: @jjanes  I wouldn't, but then my other (history) partition would be from `-infinity` to `infinity` like so:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRKWcFHHFikxuv3WC19rFL/0  Edit to add:  I do not think I would ever use partitioning for this without a lot of further testing, though.  Plus I'm one of those clowns who would put `'9999-12-31'` in my live records instead of `null`

Comment: Thanks @Mike Organek.  I thought about the default partition, but there are two drawbacks 1) when I add a new partition Postgres will scan the entire default partition to see of it needs to copy records from there to the newly created partition.  If the nulls will go to their own non-default partition this will be skipped.  2) I prefer to keep the default partition to catch problematic dates that do not have partitions (future dates, very old dates).